# How to debug GLSL Fragment shader (Program Linking error after code change)

Tags: debugging, opengl, compilation, glsl

**(original Title)** Please help me debug my glsl lighting shader so that it will compile! This is my first time debugging glsl

Hello I am VERY new to opengl.  I am working on modifying another shader I found online.  The version I found online works just great, however somewhere along in my code I made a mistake while editing.  The problem is I have combed through it and can not see it, I was hoping for some fresh eyes.

To be clear it is not that what is being drawn is incorrect, it flat out wont compile

```
#version 330 core
struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float shininess;
    float ambient;
}; 

struct DirLight {
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 color;
    float strength;
};

struct PointLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
    float strength;
    float active;
};

struct SpotLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;       
};

#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 150

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform DirLight dirLight;
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLight;
uniform Material material;

// Function prototypes
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir, vec3 fcolor);
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);

void main()
{    
    // Properties
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 fragColor = texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords).rgb;
    // == ======================================
    // Our lighting is set up in 3 phases: directional, point lights and an optional flashlight
    // For  each phase, a calculate function is defined that calculates the corresponding color
    // per lamp. In the main() function we take all the calculated colors and sum them up for
    // this fragment's final color.
    // == ======================================
    // Phase 1: Directional lighting
    vec3 result = vec3(0.0f);
    //result = CalcDirLight(dirLight, norm, viewDir);

    // Phase 2: Point lights
    for(int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
     {
       result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], norm, FragPos, viewDir, fragColor);  
    }  
    // Phase 3: Spot light
   //result += CalcSpotLight(spotLight, norm, FragPos, viewDir);    

    result += material.ambient * fragColor;
    color = vec4(result, 1.0);
}

// Calculates the color when using a directional light.
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    return (diffuse + specular);
}

// Calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir, vec3 fcolor)
{
    if (light.active == 1)
    {
        // Lighting
        vec3 lighting = vec3(0.0f);
        //  Diffuse
         vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
         float diff = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0);
         vec3 result = light.color * diff * fcolor;      
         // Attenuation (use quadratic as we have gamma correction)
         float distance = (length(fragPos - light.position)/light.strength);
         result *= 1.0 / (distance * distance);
         lighting += result;

        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
        vec3 specular = spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords)) * light.color;
        specular *= material.shininess;

        specular *= 1.0 / (distance * distance);

        vec3 toReturn = lighting + specular;
        return toReturn;
    }
    else
    {
        return vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
}

// Calculates the color when using a spot light.
vec3 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // Attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0f / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // Spotlight intensity
    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction)); 
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;
    return (diffuse + specular);
}
```

And thankfully my program does print out errors on compilation.  This is what is spat out.  Unfortunately the lines it points to are not real.... like they exist but they dont have any problems, heck one of the errors pointed to a line with no code on it....  I havent changed the fragment shader from its origional part so it can't be the issue

Picture of error can be found at: https://app.box.com/s/3nrzjyu3p2smnow5zo8j0q1lbqgdf149
[image]

I have tried glslDevil but i cant figure out how to import my shaders.

Thanks much!

EDIT: 
Intersting thing i found...
An interesting thing i have noticed is that if you define the Directional light function as so

```
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    return (diffuse + specular);
}
```

It only throws an error that diffuse, specular , and ambient arent a member of that struct (which is intentional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors log of yours are not good**

- it is some linking log from the tool you are using
- not the **OpenGL** compilation log !!!

**I put your fragment shader into OpenGL and this is the real compilation log (nVidia used):**

```
[Fragment]
Compiler error
0(94) : error C1009: "ambient" is not member of struct "DirLight"
0(95) : error C1009: "diffuse" is not member of struct "DirLight"
0(96) : error C1009: "specular" is not member of struct "DirLight"

[Program]
Linker error
Fragment info
-------------
0(94) : error C1009: "ambient" is not member of struct "DirLight"
0(95) : error C1009: "diffuse" is not member of struct "DirLight"
0(96) : error C1009: "specular" is not member of struct "DirLight"
```

- you should use `glGetShaderInfoLog` for every shader/program object you use in **OpenGL**
- I use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214)

**It makes sense:**

```
vec3 CalcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCoords));
    return (diffuse + specular);
}
```

**After the `// Combine results` you are accessing `struct` fields that are not defined in:**

```
struct DirLight {
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 color;
    float strength;
};
```

**[edit1] in C++ I use this class of mine for GLSL:**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- GLSL program class -------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class GLSLprogram       // GLSL program class
    {
public:
    AnsiString log;
    int prog_id,    // whole program
        tesc_id,    // tessellation control
        tese_id,    // tessellation evaluation
        geom_id,    // geometry
        vert_id,    // vertex
        frag_id;    // fragment

    GLSLprogram();
    GLSLprogram(GLSLprogram& a);
    ~GLSLprogram();
    GLSLprogram* operator = (const GLSLprogram *a);
    //GLSLprogram* operator = (const GLSLprogram &a);
    void bind();
    void unbind();

    void set_source_text(AnsiString tesc,AnsiString tese,AnsiString geom,AnsiString vert,AnsiString frag);  // set source texts
    void set_source_file(AnsiString tesc,AnsiString tese,AnsiString geom,AnsiString vert,AnsiString frag);  // load and set source files

    void set1f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x);
    void set2f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y);
    void set3f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z);
    void set4f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w);
    void set1i   (AnsiString name,GLint x);
    void set2i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y);
    void set3i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y, GLint z);
    void set4i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y, GLint z, GLint w);
    void set1fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set2fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set3fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set4fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set1iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void set2iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void set3iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void set4iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void set2x2fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set3x3fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void set4x4fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);

    void get1f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat &x);
    void get2f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat &x, GLfloat &y);
    void get3f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat &x, GLfloat &y, GLfloat &z);
    void get4f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat &x, GLfloat &y, GLfloat &z, GLfloat &w);
    void get1i   (AnsiString name,GLint &x);
    void get2i   (AnsiString name,GLint &x, GLint &y);
    void get3i   (AnsiString name,GLint &x, GLint &y, GLint &z);
    void get4i   (AnsiString name,GLint &x, GLint &y, GLint &z, GLint &w);
    void get1fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get2fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get3fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get4fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get1iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void get2iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void get3iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void get4iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p);
    void get2x2fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get3x3fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    void get4x4fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p);
    };
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLSLprogram::GLSLprogram()
    {
    prog_id=0;
    tesc_id=0;
    tese_id=0;
    geom_id=0;
    vert_id=0;
    frag_id=0;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLSLprogram::~GLSLprogram()
    {
    if (glDetachShader==NULL) return;
    if (glDeleteShader==NULL) return;
    unbind();
    if (tesc_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,tesc_id); glDeleteShader(tesc_id); }
    if (tese_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,tese_id); glDeleteShader(tese_id); }
    if (geom_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,geom_id); glDeleteShader(geom_id); }
    if (vert_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,vert_id); glDeleteShader(vert_id); }
    if (frag_id>0) { glDetachShader(prog_id,frag_id); glDeleteShader(frag_id); }
    if (prog_id>0) {                                  glDeleteShader(prog_id); }
    log="";
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::bind()
    {
    if (glUseProgram==NULL) return;
    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::unbind()
    {
    if (glUseProgram==NULL) return;
    glUseProgram(0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::set_source_text(AnsiString tesc,AnsiString tese,AnsiString geom,AnsiString vert,AnsiString frag)
    {
    if (glCreateProgram==NULL) return;
    if (glShaderSource==NULL) return;
    if (glCompileShader==NULL) return;
    if (glAttachShader==NULL) return;
    if (glGetShaderiv==NULL) return;
    if (glGetShaderInfoLog==NULL) return;
    if (glLinkProgram==NULL) return;

    if (glGetProgramiv==NULL) return;
    if (glGetProgramInfoLog==NULL) return;
    if (glReleaseShaderCompiler==NULL) return;

    const int _size=1024;
    char dat[_size];
    GLint status,siz=0,i;
    const char * TC = tesc.c_str();
    const char * TE = tese.c_str();
    const char * GS = geom.c_str();
    const char * VS = vert.c_str();
    const char * FS = frag.c_str();
    log="";

    if (prog_id<=0) prog_id=glCreateProgram();

    if (tesc_id<=0) tesc_id=glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    else glDetachShader(prog_id,tesc_id);
    if (tesc!="")
        {
        glShaderSource(tesc_id, 1, &TC,NULL);
        glCompileShader(tesc_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,tesc_id);
        glGetShaderiv(tesc_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        log+="[Tessellation control]\n";
        if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Compiler error\n";
        glGetShaderInfoLog(tesc_id,_size,&siz,dat);
        for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];

        }

    if (tese_id<=0) tese_id=glCreateShader(GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
    else glDetachShader(prog_id,tese_id);
    if (tese!="")
        {
        glShaderSource(tese_id, 1, &TE,NULL);
        glCompileShader(tese_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,tese_id);
        glGetShaderiv(tese_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        log+="[Tessellation evaluation]\n";
        if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Compiler error\n";
        glGetShaderInfoLog(tese_id,_size,&siz,dat);
        for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];

        }
    if (geom_id<=0) geom_id=glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    else glDetachShader(prog_id,geom_id);
    if (geom!="")
        {
        glShaderSource(geom_id, 1, &GS,NULL);
        glCompileShader(geom_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,geom_id);
        glGetShaderiv(geom_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        log+="[Geometry]\n";
        if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Compiler error\n";
        glGetShaderInfoLog(geom_id,_size,&siz,dat);
        for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];

        }
    if (vert_id<=0) vert_id=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    else glDetachShader(prog_id,vert_id);
    if (vert!="")
        {
        glShaderSource(vert_id, 1, &VS,NULL);
        glCompileShader(vert_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,vert_id);
        glGetShaderiv(vert_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        log+="[Vertex]\n";
        if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Compiler error\n";
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vert_id,_size,&siz,dat);
        for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];
        }
    if (frag_id<=0) frag_id=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    else glDetachShader(prog_id,frag_id);
    if (frag!="")
        {
        glShaderSource(frag_id, 1, &FS,NULL);
        glCompileShader(frag_id);
        glAttachShader(prog_id,frag_id);
        glGetShaderiv(frag_id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        log+="\n[Fragment]\n";
        if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Compiler error\n";
        glGetShaderInfoLog(frag_id,_size,&siz,dat);
        for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];
        }

    glLinkProgram(prog_id);
    glGetProgramiv(prog_id,GL_LINK_STATUS,&status);
    log+="\n[Program]\n";
    if (status) log+="OK\n"; else log+="Linker error\n";
    glGetProgramInfoLog(prog_id,_size,&siz,dat);
    for (i=0;i<siz;i++) log+=dat[i];

    glReleaseShaderCompiler();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::set_source_file(AnsiString tesc,AnsiString tese,AnsiString geom,AnsiString vert,AnsiString frag)
    {
    set_source_text(load(tesc),load(tese),load(geom),load(vert),load(frag));
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::set1f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x)                                 { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform1f  (id,x);       }
void GLSLprogram::set2f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y)                      { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform2f  (id,x,y);     }
void GLSLprogram::set3f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)           { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform3f  (id,x,y,z);   }
void GLSLprogram::set4f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat w){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform4f  (id,x,y,z,w); }
void GLSLprogram::set1i   (AnsiString name,GLint x)                                   { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform1i  (id,x);       }
void GLSLprogram::set2i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y)                          { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform2i  (id,x,y);     }
void GLSLprogram::set3i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y, GLint z)                 { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform3i  (id,x,y,z);   }
void GLSLprogram::set4i   (AnsiString name,GLint x, GLint y, GLint z, GLint w)        { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform4i  (id,x,y,z,w); }
void GLSLprogram::set1fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform1fv (id,1,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set2fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform2fv (id,2,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set3fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform3fv (id,3,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set4fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform4fv (id,4,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set1iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)                                  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform1iv (id,1,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set2iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)                                  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform2iv (id,2,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set3iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)                                  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform3iv (id,3,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set4iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)                                  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniform4iv (id,4,p);     }
void GLSLprogram::set2x2fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLboolean q=true; GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniformMatrix2fv(id, 4,q,p); }
void GLSLprogram::set3x3fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLboolean q=true; GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniformMatrix3fv(id, 9,q,p); }
void GLSLprogram::set4x4fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p)                                { GLboolean q=true; GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glUniformMatrix4fv(id,16,q,p); }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GLSLprogram::get1f   (AnsiString name,GLfloat &x){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,&x); }
void GLSLprogram::get1i   (AnsiString name,GLint &x)  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformiv(prog_id,id,&x); }
void GLSLprogram::get1fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get2fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get3fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get4fv  (AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get1iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformiv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get2iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformiv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get3iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformiv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get4iv  (AnsiString name,GLint *p)  { GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformiv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get2x2fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get3x3fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
void GLSLprogram::get4x4fv(AnsiString name,GLfloat *p){ GLint id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,name.c_str()); glGetUniformfv(prog_id,id,p);  }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- `AnsiString` is just **VCL** string class (self relocable string class) can use anything else like `char[]` or `char*` instead but you need to handle operators of coarse...
- `AnsiString().c_str()` returns `char*` compatible pointer to stored string

**usage:**

```
// [variables]
GLSLprogram   shader;
// [init]
shader.set_source_text("","","","your vertex shader source text","your fragment shader source text");
shader.log; // contains the compile/link log ...
shader.prog_id; // contains the OpenGL id for your shader object


// [render]
shader.bind();
// here render
shader.unbind();
```

**[edit2] And also I forget to add:**

```
AnsiString load(AnsiString file)
    {
    int i,hnd,siz;
    char *dat=NULL;
    hnd=FileOpen(file,fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return "";
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    if (siz==0) { FileClose(hnd); return ""; }
    dat=new char[siz+1];
    if (dat==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return ""; }
    FileRead(hnd,dat,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);
    AnsiString s=""; for (i=0;i<siz;i++) s+=dat[i];
    delete dat;
    return s;
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou!  It was such a stupid errror to make.  Could you link me to how you used this "real compilation log"?

Comment: @ShaderWriter just search the code for `glGetShaderInfoLog` and see how it is used ...