# uniform sampler2D in Vertex Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I tried to realize height map with GLSL.
For it, i need to sent my picture to VertexShader and get grey component.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
Texture.bind();

glUniform1i(mShader.getUniformLocation("heightmap"), 0);
```

*mShader.getUniformLocation* uses **glGetUniformLocation** and work good for other uniforms values, that used in Fragment, Vertex Shaders. But for **heightmap** **return** **-1**...

VertexShader code:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoords;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 ourColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

uniform sampler2D heightmap;

void main()
{
    float bias = 0.25;
    float h = 0.0;
    float scale = 5.0;

       h = scale * ((texture2D(heightmap, texCoords).r) - bias);
        vec3 hnormal = vec3(normal.x*h, normal.y*h, normal.z*h);
        vec3 position1 = position * hnormal;
       gl_Position = projection * view *  model * vec4(position1, 1.0f);


    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoords = texCoords;
}
```

may be algorithm of getting height is bad, but error with getting uniformlocation stops my work..
What is wrong? Any ideas?

**UPD:** texCoords (not TexCoords) of course is using in

```
h = scale * ((texture2D(heightmap, texCoords).r) - bias);
```

my mistake, but it doesn't solve the problem. Having same error..

Comment: your change in the code is now compilable/linkable without problems. The uniform is found on my setup (nVidia). Are you using `glGetUniformLocation` after your shader is binded ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet is your variable has been optimized out by driver or the shader did not compile/link properly. After trying to compile your shader (on my **nVidia**) I got this in the logs:

```
0(9) : warning C7050: "TexCoords" might be used before being initialized
```

You should always check the **GLSL** compile/link logs ? see

- [How to debug GLSL Fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716794/2521214)

especially how the `glGetShaderInfoLog`  is used.

**In line**

```
h = scale * ((texture2D(heightmap, TexCoords).r) - bias);
```

You are using `TexCoords` which is output variable and not yet set so the behavior is undefined and most likely your gfx driver throw that line away (and may be others) removing the `TexCoords` from shader completely but that is just my assumption.

**What driver and gfx card you got?**

**What returns the logs on your setup?**