# What is the equivalent of glNormal3fv in shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, normals

Thanks for taking the time to read this. 
I am modifying my OpenGL application to use GLSL shaders, its purpose is to visualize 3D atomistic models, including tetrahedra (and other polyhedra) using GL_TRIANGLES.

Note: in the examples bellow, colors and alpha channels are identicals.

Before I had:

```
void triangle (GLFloat * va, GLFloat * vb, GLFloat * vc)
{
   glVertex3fv (va);
   glVertex3fv (vb);
   glVertex3fv (vc);
}
void tetra (GLFloat ** xyz)
{
  // xyz Contains the coordinates of the triangles
  // ie. the 4 peaks of the tetrahedra
  // bellow 'get_normal' compute the normals
  glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
  glNormal3fv (get_normal(xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]));
  triangle (xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]);
  glNormal3fv (get_normal(xyz[1], xyz[2], xyz[3]));
  triangle (xyz[1], xyz[2], xyz[3]);
  glNormal3fv (get_normal(xyz[2], xyz[3], xyz[0]));
  triangle (xyz[2], xyz[3], xyz[0]);
  glNormal3fv (get_normal(xyz[0], xyz[3], xyz[1]));
  triangle (xyz[0], xyz[3], xyz[1]);
  glEnd ();
}
```

That displayed (the proper result):

[image: First version of the code using glNormal3fv + glVertex3fv]

Then I modified the code to use the following shaders:

```
#define GLSL(src) "#version 130\n" #src

const GLchar * vertex = GLSL(
  uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projMatrix;
  in vec3 position;
  in float size;
  in vec4 color;
  out vec4 vert_color;
  void main()
  {
    vert_color = color;
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
);

const GLchar * colors = GLSL(
  in vec4 vert_color;
  out vec4 vertex_color;
  void main()
  {
    vertex_color = vert_color;
  }
);
```

And now I got:

[image: New version of the code using Vertex and Fragment shaders]

So obviously something is wrong with the colors/lighting, and I whish I could understand how to correct this, I think that I have to use geometry shaders but I do not know where to find the information to now how/what to do, 
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe a trivial thing, but it seems You do not use the normals in Your shaders. You should define it (just like color or size) as an input for them.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I tried to, but I do not know how to use it in the shader, note I do not know how to use the 'size' variable either, I wanted to use it to define point size of line width but so far I can not figure out how :-P

Comment: And how do You actually do the draw call with the shaders? Generally one should bind the shaders to be used instead of fixed functionality as far as I remember. But still the vertex data have to be passed to GL (like in the glBegin/glEnd part).

Comment: "*`#define GLSL(src) "#version 130\n" #src`*" Really? In 2017? Has ***nobody*** in the OpenGL community heard of *raw string literals*? What is it with OpenGL users acting like C++ has never gotten any features since 2003?

Comment: @NicolBolas are you? Because according to your profile you're an OpenGL user aswell :p

Comment: As to the question: when you use shaders you have to do shading, duh? ;)

Comment: see [OpenGL - vertex normals in OBJ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) for the new style OpenGl normal use and [How can I render an 'atmosphere' over a rendering of the Earth in Three.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) for the old style ... Also read this: [Explenation of working principle of openGL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32047055/2521214) btw computing normals during rendering will be slow ... precompute once instead ...

Comment: @Spektre thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for, really appreciate that you point me to right direction !