# is TBN matrix really rotation matrix in nature?

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader

I've seen someguy's shader snippet, that the composed TBN matrix was used to transform the attribute a_pos.but obviously it's not related to bump-maping,or anything else. could this be rotation matrix made from  input parameters of the shader? those vectors(normal,binormal,tangent) are nothing more than three bases, aren't they?

I mean the TBN matrix of the shader is not used to be the TBN matrix applied on bump-maping ever (as you know, to transform a vector to vector in tangent space,or to transform vector in tangent back using inverse of TBN matrix),  and there 's no light calculation involved in. a little bit confusion in my mind.

Hope your guy help me get through it. sorry for my bad english,thank you!

Here's the shader, as the following:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#else
#define highp
#define mediump
#define lowp
#endif
uniform   mat4 u_mvp;

attribute vec3 a_pos;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_uv0;
attribute vec2 a_uv1;

varying   vec2 v_texcoord0;
varying   vec2 v_texcoordMap;

uniform highp float u_time;
uniform mediump float u_1DivLevelWidth;
uniform mediump float u_1DivLevelHeight;

void main()
{
    float mapPos = a_normal.x * 0.1 + a_normal.y * 0.6;
    vec2 v1 = vec2(cos(mapPos + u_time * 0.6), cos(mapPos + u_time * 0.9));
    mapPos = (a_normal.x + a_normal.y + a_pos.x + a_pos.y) * 3.0;
    vec2 v2 = vec2(cos(mapPos + u_time * 3.2 + (a_uv1.y * 0.1)), cos(mapPos + u_time * 2.9 + (a_uv1.y * 0.1))) * 0.02 * a_uv1.y;



    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(v1 * (a_uv1.x * 0.2), 5.0));
    //vec3 normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 binormal = normalize(cross(normal, vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
    vec3 tangent = normalize(cross(binormal, normal));


    // to transform the position using the above TBN matrix
    // what's the TBN matrix meaning for 
    vec4 pos = vec4((a_pos * mat3(tangent, binormal, normal)) + a_normal, 1.0) + vec4(v2 * (a_uv1.y * 0.2), 0.0, 0.0);

    gl_Position = u_mvp * pos;
    v_texcoord0 = a_uv0;
    v_texcoordMap = vec2(pos.x * u_1DivLevelWidth, pos.y * u_1DivLevelHeight);
}
```

Comment: "*could this be rotation matrix made from some input parameters,just three basis?*" It's not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: hi,@Nicol Bolas. i've made that description clear and unambiguous。

Answer (score 1):

**TBN** matrix is [transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) converting between rasterised primitive and world coordinates. The 3 vectors represent your rotation matrix and origin is usually placed to `(0,0,0)` or to one of the vertexes.

The answer to your question depends on the **TBN** usage. If you are using it only for vectors (like for directional light computations or **bump mapping**) then yes **TBN** can be just rotation matrix. But if you need transform also positions then you need full matrix with origin.

see related **QA**: [Normal mapping gone horribly wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214) where **TBN** is used as rotation 3x3 matrix.