# What am I doing wrong, in regards to multi-texture(OpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, fragment-shader

I am writing a bump mapping demo, so I need an image texture, and a normal texture which should be loaded into the fragment shader.

---

This is the texture part of my OpenGL code:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brick);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLint textureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "texture");
glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
GLuint normal_textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &normal_textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, normal_textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    brick_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLint normalTextureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "normal_texture");
glUniform1i(normalTextureLocation, 1);
```

Here is the fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 light;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D normal_texture;

void main() {
    vec3 tex = texture2D(normal_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex, 1.0);
}
```

---

I am sure that the `brick` array contains the image texture, and the `brick_texture` array contains the normal texture; but it seems `normal_texture` and `texture` are both the image texture, not the normal texture. What am I doing wrong, in regards to multi-texture?

Comment: look at this for comparison [Normal mapping gone horribly wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214) btw I do not see any `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` for any of the units ... Also did you check [glGetInfoLog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) in case your shader has some bug and did not compile/link?

Comment: @Spektre: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` isn't a per-unit state, and isn't needed with the programmable pipeline -- it's obsolete with OpenGL 3.1+.

Answer (score 2):

Since one of your *uniform samplers* is unreferenced, the other gets optimized out. This causes both `textureLocation` and `normalTextureLocation` to be equal and name the one sampler that is referenced. Therefore the latest you set, which is the image texture, take precedence over the normal texture. You can verify this by referencing both samplers:

```
void main() {
    vec3 tex0 = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;
    vec3 tex1 = texture2D(normal_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex0.r, tex1.gb, 1.0);
}
```

You should see the red channel from the diffuse and green and blue channels from the normal.

In the future use [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) or check for errors to catch such bugs.